# PHP width screen with different display

Tags: php

i have a background that i want to use jpg+video or jpg to display. If it is desktop screen then show jpg+video, else show jpg background if its iphone or ipad size. In PHP coding. I am thinking maybe can use if-statement but i am not sure. Please help!

Below is to show on desktop/laptop screen size:

```
<div id="header-bg"> 
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volumne="0">
<source src="images/show-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="images/show-bg.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="images/show-bg.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Video not supported
</video>
```

Below is to show on iPhone/ipad size:

```
<div id="header-bg1">
```

"header-bg" and "header-bg1" are linked to CSS.

Below are the CSS:

```
#header-bg {background: url(../images/header/show-bg.png) 0% 0 no-repeat;}
#header-bg1 {background: url(../images/header/show-bg.jpg) 0% 0 no-repeat;}
#video_background {position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width= auto; height: auto; z-index: -1000; overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: You're better off using `@media screen` CSS. PHP alone, cannot determine client-side settings. Either CSS and/or use JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should decide on server (PHP) side. Add [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) javascript library to your page and use its feature detection.

Comment: This is a link only answer, which are generally not encouraged. Think what will happen in 4 years when your link dies. Will there be anything left to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Might take a bunch of extra code to specifically target an iPad and such but this JavaScript might work:

```
<script>
    if ( $( window ).width() > 1024 {
        document.write("
            <div id="header-bg"></div>
            <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"  muted="muted" volumne="0">
                <source src="images/show-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="images/show-bg.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="images/show-bg.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                Video not supported
            </video>
         ");
    } else {
        document.write("
            <div id="header-bg1"></div>
        ");
    }
</script>
```

If you use media screen then you would put something like this in the `<head>`. This will require separate stylesheets or create one stylesheet and use the second part:

```
<head>
    <link href="" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Should target iPads -->
    <link href="" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Should target iPhones -->
</head>
```

One stylesheet, add this at the bottom of the stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    css goes here {
    }
}    

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    css goes here {
    }
}
```

Try adding `display: none` on what you don't want to show on a mobile device but do on a PC and vice versa. The media queries will overwrite whatever you put in the main CSS as well.

Comment: Hi, i have tried this before but it shows blank background. Both video and jpg also doesnt show up. Wonder why...

Comment: Still not working. Fred commented it needs to use @media screen CSS. Do you know? I am not a programmer. Thanks.

Comment: Updated, not sure if that helps either though.